# Scraping a img alt class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape the src from this:

```
<img alt class="_2r9Zh0W" data-auto-id="productTileImage" sizes="(min-width: 768px) 317px, 238px" src="https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-unrvlld-supply-slip-on-tech-slippers-in-navy-borg-on-black-sole/21009025-1-navy?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain"
```

From this website:

```
https://www.asos.com/men/new-in/new-in-shoes/cat/?cid=17184&currentpricerange=10-400&nlid=mw%7Cnew%20in%7Cnew%20products&page=1&sort=freshness
```

This is the code I am running, I have currently managed to scrape the Title, Price, URL.

```
array = output.find_all('article', {'class': '_2qG85dG'})
        for ele in array:
            item = [ele.find('div', {'class': '_3J74XsK'}).text.replace('\n',''), #title
                    ele.find('span', {'class': '_16nzq18'}).text.replace('\n',''), #pricing
                    ele.find('a', {'class': '_3TqU78D'})['href'], #URL
                    ele.find('img', {'class': '_2r9Zh0W'})['src']]
            self.all_items.append(item)
```

Comment: alt class isn't a thing. `alt` is a separate attribute

Comment: Oh okay, How would I go about scraping that image then? Sorry I am fairly new to bs4

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
ele.find('img', {'class': '_2r9Zh0W'})['alt']
```

to item. The image you are using doesn't actually have content in the alt tag. The above code should return an empty string.

Comment: Not sure I did it right. I replaced the last line of item with yours and it returned - 
```ele.find('img', {'class': '_2r9Zh0W'})['alt']]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```